# How many times will this loop execute in C#?

Tags: c#

```
int x = 1;
while (x++ < 5)
{
    if ((x % 2) == 0)
        x += 2;
}
```

Question is how many times the following loop will executed?
As I can see the 1st x equals to 1, 2nd x equals to 2, 3rd x equals to 4, I thought it will execute 3 times, but why the answer is 2 times?

Comment: If you're going to ask a C# question, please post real C# code, or at least say that it is pseudo-code. Neither `Int` nor `While` is legal C# code, and you're missing semicolons, and using an invalid character for the comparison.

Comment: Have you tried to debug, and watch the variables? it's a simple scenario to follow

Comment: Homework is created to make you learn, not to make you ask on Internet...

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-explanation-of-this-code-Int-x-1-while-x++-5-if-x-2-0-x-+-2-Console-WriteLine-x

Comment: thx for reply guys, I'm using my mobile to ask this question,sorry for the capital letters, I don't have a PC with me right now,I'm just looking into codes

Comment: @user8555504 .. You Can Check Solution HERE: at Quora Your Code is Explained Clearly :)  https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-explanation-of-this-code-Int-x-1-while-x++-5-if-x-2-0-x-+-2-Console-WriteLine-x

Comment: Anyway, the thing you are missing is the `++` operator. right after the comparison, the value of `x` is incremented. So, in the first iteration of the loop the value of x after the comparison is `2` not `1`.

Answer (score 5):

As you've stated, the body of the while loop will indeed execute two times, and not three.

Here's why.

I'll unroll the loop so that we can see what happens.

```
int x = 1;                 // x is now 1
while (x++ < 5)            // read the current value of x, which is 1
                           // then increase x by 1, giving it the value 2
                           // then compare the value we read (1) with 5
                           // since 1 < 5, we will execute the body of
                           // the while loop
{
    if (x % 2 == 0)        // x is equal to 2, "2 % 2" is equal to 0
                           // so execute the body of the if-statement
        x += 2;            // increase x by 2, giving it the value 4
}
// while (x++ < 5)         // read the current value of x, which is 4
                           // then increase x by 1, giving it the value 5
                           // then compare the value we read (4) with 5
                           // since 4 < 5, we will execute the body of
                           // the while loop
{
    if (x % 2 == 0)        // x is equal to 5, "5 % 2" is NOT equal to 0
                           // so do not execute the body of the if-statement
}
// while (x++ < 5)         // read the current value of x, which is 5
                           // then increase x by 1, giving it the value 6
                           // then compare the value we read (5) with 5
                           // since 5 < 5 is not true, we will NOT
                           // execute the body of the while loop
```

And we're done

Final value of `x` is `6`.

So the answer is, as you stated, that the body of the while loop executes twice.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `++` right operator in your `while` loop. So everytime you get through this condition, your x value is incremented by one when entering the loop. So your x value is tested with the value 1, and then incremented by one, making it equal to 2 when entering the loop for the first time. You then meets the if condition, increasing x value by 2. When you get back to your while condition, x is equal to 4. You get in another time with the tested value 4, and increase its value again by 1. It's then equal to 5. When getting back to your while condition the third time, x is equal to 5, so you don't meet the condition anymore. You just entered your while loop two times, and not three.

Comment: Wrong, the evaluation of `x++` returns the value before the increment, to use the logic you describe you would need `++x`. In either case x would be the incremented value inside the loop.

Comment: @BobVale I don't see where I did stated what you just said though. I said that when you entered the loop again after meeting the condition, x value was incremented, not before. Maybe I am unclear in my statement though, in that case I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I found your answer unclear and may have misread it. I've removed my downvote.  I read that as only hitting the while condition twice, which would be true for `++x`. While is hit 3 times, but loop contents only processed twice

Answer (score 1):

Ok first you need to understand how ++ works.

With ++ on the right the value is incremented but the previous value returned.

- `x++` evaluated to `1`, but is `2` inside the loop so `x % 2 == 0`, `x=4`
- `x++` evaluated to `4`, but is `5` inside the loop so `x % 2 != 0`, `x=5`
- `x++` evaluated to `5` loop exits, final value of `x` is `6`